# What flying sources does Richard Feynman consider incorrect?

Tags: theory

In this [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYPapE-3FRw&list=PLyQSN7X0ro23NUN9RYBP5xdBYoiv2_5y2&ab_channel=seabala) from 1:09-2:15 Richard Feynman talk about some flying sources that he considers incorrect.

What is the theory that he refers to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He's talking about "[Flying Saucers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_saucer)" not flying sources.

This is even clearer when you listen at 2:00 where he refers "known irrational characteristics of terrestrial intelligence" vs the "unknown rational characteristics of extraterrestrial intelligence".

Comment: Note this might have been my copy editing - the word was originally was "soruces"

Comment: @Jamiec I don't think that your editing is the culpript

Comment: @Federico Ok thanks :)

Comment: Mr. Feynman speaks with a distinct New York accent.  Very difficult distinguish "saucers" from "sources" in my opinion.

Comment: Is this english.se or aviation.se? 