# Does “balls to the wall” mean “full speed ahead” or “full speed ahead and nosedive”?

Tags: aviation-history, terminology

Full speed ahead: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/balls_to_the_wall

Full speed ahead and nosedive: https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2006/02/why-we-say-balls-to-the-wall.html

Comment: It is unfortunate that that Slate article exists. It is wrong and it is being used as a reference in the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: [Citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/) at work, perhaps?

Comment: [Again](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/96359/what-flying-sources-does-richard-feynman-consider-incorrect#comment266371_96360): is this english.se or aviation.se? 

Comment: *I said the WALL... not the ceiling!* [*How many {morons} do we have on this ship?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Mv1s4Xj7bk)

Answer (score 22):

When used in aviation it just means "everything forward" for maximum performance, everything being throttles, propeller RPM levers, and mixture control levers, where you need maximum performance. Not flight controls. It has nothing to do with diving; it's just a reference to maximum power.

The "balls" are the knobs traditionally used on throttle quadrants back in the 20s and 30s. The "wall" is represented by the instrument panel forward of the quadrant, or possibly the firewall in a single engine airplane.

When an engine quits on takeoff, one of first memory items is to confirm that all three sets of controls, throttle, prop and mixture, are all the way forward.

Supercharged piston engines of the day had a manifold pressure red line setting that you had to manage. You weren't just supposed to push the throttle all the way, you adjust it until the MP gauge is at a redline mark.

In an emergency however, you may elect to ignore the manifold pressure limit and make the engine produce whatever it could. In WW2 aircraft, there was a War Emergency Power setting, usually with a "gate" made of, or retained by, copper witness wire that would form a normal limit stop, but which you could break through if you pushed hard enough, to get everything the engine had (and probably damaging it in the process, which is why the witness wire).

Anyway, in an airplane like a DC-3 it's 6 balls, one on top of each lever. So it's a short-form and amusing slang description of shoving all of the engine control levers fully forward.

Another very similar phrase used commonly in aviation for throttles is to say "firewall it".  It means shove the throttle fully forward, with the joking inference or suggestion that you ram it so hard your fist ends up in the engine firewall.

Comment: Got it, so "Balls to the wall" is the aviation equivalent of the term "Floor" used in cars.

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  There's similar phrase in flying, where you say "firewall it".

Comment: I’d say it’s more analogous to “pedal to the metal”

Comment: Yeah 'firewall it' could've originated with cars, but normally it would be 'floor it'.

Comment: _The "balls" are the knobs traditionally used on throttle quadrants_ I always assumed  "balls" were an anatomic reference.  TIL!

Comment: One could also use "balls to the wall" to refer to the behavior of a flywheel governor at maximum RPM/power, where the flyweights are fully extended to the governor's outer casing, hence "balls to the wall"

Comment: Except that doesn't really make a lot of sense.  But if you find an instance written somewhere that predates the 1920s, it becomes plausible.

Comment: And there's me thinking it meant go so hard that if you nailed your testicles to the wall, you wouldn't notice...

Answer (score 2):

It actually means "to cut every piece of red tape, do everything they could..."

My point is, it's slang.  It's old slang. It certainly isn't official aviation phraseology where a definition could be looked up.

So really it means whatever the user intends it to mean in the context where it is used.  I don't think you will get a more definitive answer than what's provided by the two links you posted in the question.

Personally I would vote against the control stick being one of the "balls".  They aren't shaped as balls, and I don't think diving is intended, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: shapes like balls: I think some were. P51 A/B Mustang perhaps.